# Fetching Location if app is suspended/closed in IOS 9

Tags: ios, location, swift2, cllocationmanager

iOS used: 9

i am trying to retrieve location updates when the app is suspended. i know how to do this if the app is in background or foreground mode but if it is suspended how is it done in iOS 9? currently i tried logging my location to a text file but nothing was logged.
here is my code. of course i enabled location updates un background mode and edited my plist file.

in didFinishWithLaunchOptions

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if let launchOpts = launchOptions
    {

    if ((launchOpts[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) != nil)
    {
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
    }

func foundLocation(location: CLLocation!)
    {

        let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
        let logsPath = documentsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(NSLocalizedString("FolderName", comment: ""))

        let filePath = logsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent(String("textfile.txt"));

        if let outputStream = NSOutputStream(toFileAtPath: filePath.path!, append: true) {
            outputStream.open()
                outputStream.write("/***/ Text: \(location)\n\r")

            outputStream.close()
        } else {
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        foundLocation(manager.location) // update the user object in this method

    }
```

Comment: when you close the app , applicationWillTerminate will get hit, save your app data in that method!

Comment: If your app is suspended you can't do anything.